# Where is the setting Taxonomy Menu Trails?

Tags: drupal-7

where is the setting Taxonomy Menu Trails in Drupal 7? 
on Drupal 6 it was admin/settings/taxonomy-menu-trails

Answer (score 0):

You could try to nest the taxonomy on the edit page. For example: /admin/structure/taxonomy/. There you can edit the weight.

Also this module could help: https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_trails